# Как управлять значением поля id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)?

Tags: sqlalchemy

можно и нужно ли как-то управлять значением следующего поля?
id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
у меня при добавлении объекта в БД, полю id почему-то присваивается уже существующее в базе значение, хотя оно должно быть уникальным. Такая проблема появилась при переезде на новую БД в которую скопировал таблицы из старой. Выскакивает ошибка IntegrityError duplicate key value violates unique constraint